# Addthis Twitter Follow Button Customize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter, addthis

I'm currently using Addthis for my social media share / follow buttons, the problem I'm facing is on the twitter follow button I don't want it to display the username (so the button isn't so wide) I just want the word follow and the counter, I'm displaying this follow button like so on my site,

**Twitter Follow**

```
<a class="addthis_button_twitter_follow_native" tw:screen_name="myaccount"></a>
```

And once this has loaded I took a look at the source code and noticed that it loads a `<span>` element with the id `#1` and inside that is a `<b>` tag and that's where the username is so I need to remove `#1 b` but when I try to do this with css `#1 b { display: none !important;}` or with jQuery `$('#1 b').remove()` its not working, does anyone have any suggestions or other approaches to this, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check Twitter api here...https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet

You can customize your self there.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate followers count just use,

`data-show-count="true"`

and for removing user name from button,

```
data-show-screen-name="false"
```

Now it only shows the follow button and count of followers and here is the full code,

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" class="twitter-follow-button" data-align="left" data-show-screen-name="false" data-show-count="true">Follow @twitterapi</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```